# Vapor 3 decoding content: do/catch for multiple post formats?

Tags: swift, vapor, vapor-fluent

I have a controller whose create action I want to accept JSON either like this:

```
{ "foo": "bar" }
```

OR like this:

```
{ "widget": { "foo": "bar" } }
```

That is, I want to accept either the widget or the widget wrapped in a containing object. Currently, the create action for my controller looks a lot like this:

```
func createHandler(_ req: Request) throws -> Future<Widget> {
  do {
    return try req.content.decode(WidgetCreateHolder.self).flatMap(to: Widget.self) {
      return createWidget(from: $0.widget)
    }
  } catch DecodingError.keyNotFound {
    return try req.content.decode(WidgetCreateObject.self).flatMap(to: Widget.self) {
      return createWidget(from: $0)
    }
  }
}
```

where `WidgetCreateObject` looks something like:

```
struct WidgetCreateObject { var foo: String? }
```

and where `WidgetCreateHolder` looks like:

```
struct WidgetCreateHolder { var widget: WidgetCreateObject }
```

That is, my create action should `try` to create a holder, but if that fails it should catch the error and try just creating the inner object (a `WidgetCreateObject`). However, when I deploy this code to Heroku and make a request with just the inner object JSON, I get this in my logs:

```
[ ERROR ] DecodingError.keyNotFound: Value required for key 'widget'. (ErrorMiddleware.swift:26)
```

even though I am trying to catch that error!

How can I get my create action to accept two different formats of JSON object?

Comment: Have 2 structures both conforming to Decodable. Let’s call the struct with widget as A1 and without widget as A2. Try to decode it as A1 if it fails try to decode it as A2. In the first case use the map operator to convert A1 to A2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out!

The `decode` method returns a `Future`, such that the actual decoding (and hence the error) occurs later, not during the do/catch. This means there's no way to catch the error with this do catch.

Luckily, `Future`s have a series of methods prepended with `catch`; the one I'm interested in is `catchFlatMap`, which accepts a closure from `Error -> Future<Decodable>`. This method 'catches' the errors thrown in the called Future, and passes the error to the closure, using the result in any downstream futures.

So I was able to change my code to:

```
func createHandler(_ req: Request) throws -> Future<Widget> {
    return try req.content.decode(WidgetCreateHolder.self).catchFlatMap({ _ in
        return try req.content.decode(WidgetCreateObject.self).map(to: WidgetCreateHolder.self) {
            return WidgetCreateHolder(widget: $0)
        }
    }).flatMap(to: Widget.self) {
        return createWidget(from: $0.widget)
    }
}
```